# remove an item from one recyclerview and add it to another

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have two recyclerviews and I want when I clicked on an item in recycler 1, remove it and add it in recycler 2. I tried to do this in the adapter but it returned null. anyone knows how to make it happen?
Update 1:

my bind method:

```
   public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.title.setText(tasks.get(position).getTitle());
        holder.description.setText(tasks.get(position).getDescription());
        if(!tasks.get(position).getActive())
            holder.checkBox.setChecked(true);
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });

        holder.checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(!holder.checkBox.isChecked()){
                    mainActivity.finishedItems.add(tasks.get(position));
                    mainActivity.items.remove(tasks.get(position));
                }
                else if(holder.checkBox.isChecked()){
                    mainActivity.items.add(tasks.get(position));
                    mainActivity.finishedItems.remove(tasks.get(position));
                }

            }
        });
    }
```

main activity:

```
    public ArrayList<TaskModel> items;
    public ArrayList<TaskModel> finishedItems;
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        items = new ArrayList<>();
        finishedItems = new ArrayList<>();

        RecyclerViewAdapter RecyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(this,items);
        listView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        listView.setAdapter(RecyclerViewAdapter);
```

ps: I have items in my arraylists, they're not empty.

Comment: Write your code also

Comment: Have you tried making an interface?

Comment: @Parth actually Sorry I'm not very experienced and I don't know how to implement that. could you give me some ideas of how to do it?

Comment: Among other problems that there's not enough code to debug: you're never calling any of the `notify...` methods on the Adapter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, nobody answered me again and I found the solution myself:
I added both Arraylists in the adapter and exchanged datas within the adapter itself.

adapter:

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<TaskModel> tasks;
    private ArrayList<TaskModel> tasks2;
    private Context context;



    public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<TaskModel> list1, ArrayList<TaskModel> list2){
        tasks = list1;
        tasks2 = list2;
        this.context = context;
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.title.setText(tasks.get(position).getTitle());
        holder.description.setText(tasks.get(position).getDescription());

        holder.checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                        tasks2.add(tasks.get(position));
                        tasks.remove(position);
                        MainActivity.listView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
                        MainActivity.finishedListView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }
```